# Can't run GAE Shiro demo source code out of the box

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, shiro

Downloaded and unzipped the GAE Shiro demo from https://github.com/cilogi/gaeshiro but couldn't get it to work.

Running `mvn appengine:devserver` causes errors because of :

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.google.appengine.devappserver.DevAppServerRunner
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:661)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:366)
```

This is right out of the box, with no modifications. Ideas?

Details:

- Mac OS X 10.9
- Java 1.7.0_45
- Maven 3.1.1

Comment: Since 1.8.3, the appengine maven plugin has two versions, one for maven versions below 3.1.0 and one for that or above.
Can you list your appengine version?

Comment: @Nick In the original pom.xml the appengine version is listed as 1.8.1.1. I tried changing this to 1.8.7, but got the same `NoClassDefFoundError`, just with a different file (`LocalServiceTestHelper`).